# PonyOverflow.com Question

Tags: discussion, fun

I'm trying to access PonyOverflow.com, but it keeps routing me to stackoverflow.com.  Does this mean I should be asking pony questions on StackOverflow until they finally finish PonyOverflow.com?

Anyway, here's my question:

What the heck is a pony anyway?  Is it a midget horse or just a brand of shoes?

Comment: *closed as "belongs on ponyoverflow.com"* :-P

Comment: How do you overflow ponies? is it a large pony given too much oats and hay? Too many ponies in a barn? How do you arrange your ponies? stack or queue. Etc.

Comment: @jrcs3: Well, I've accidentally stepped in some PonyOverflow... does that give you a hint?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PonyOverflow.com is a recursive joke.

With that said, I am looking for suggestions on how to successfully incorporate AdSense into my profile :)

As for your question: A pony is neither a midget horse (midgets are evil little impish creatures that eat babies) nor a brand of shoes (as far as I know).

Ponies are magical creatures that bring happiness and love wherever they trot. Their slightly smaller stature is due to the fact that they were never intended to be beasts of burden.

A closely related magical relative to the pony is the unicorn. Many have mistakenly believed that unicorns are weaponized forms of the pony, but they do not share the same body build and are actually more closely related to the non magical standard horse.

Comment: Just being nosy how much do you pay for domain names and if it's less then $14.99 a year, then what company is it?

Comment: The domain actually belongs to Olafur: http://whois.domaintools.com/ponyoverflow.com

Comment: Olafur registered the domain name before I could get to it but was nice enough to point it to my page. If I ever get AdSense to work in my profile, I will be sure to give him $0.47

Comment: So how can I get the beloved "OMG Meta Ponies" badge?

Comment: Solomonson: pay me $0.47

Comment: TheTXI if you want it you can email me. There's a contact email in the about me section of my website.

Answer (score 5):

I setup Ponyoverflow.com for TheTXI as a joke. We were giggling on IRC one night and he suggested we created a ponyoverflow site. I registered the domain and pointed it to his profile. Since he is the Pony King.

Comment: I knew it! ^_^         x

Comment: I imagine you both giggling and it gives me the creeps

Answer (score 2):

I think that URL simply points to TheTXI's user page - for fun.

Comment: For fun? This is serious business.

Comment: That's exactly what I said, for fun.