# Empty Space at the Bottom of the Page

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, whitespace

Why do I see this huge gap at the bottom of most pages?

[image]

Comment: You must be using the free StackOverflow, you have to pay extra to get rid of the white space (and get unicorn avatars).

Comment: @Lance: Unicorn avatars? How much? Can you pay for rep? ;-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/oh-my-godits-full-of-unicorns

Comment: That's where the secret moderator controls go for 25k+ users.

Comment: @Lance, yea Evan Carroll is so far the only user I know that's payed for "Exp"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a canvas for you to draw things you like.

See, you can do whatever you want with this blank area here. Like maybe a spider. Yeah, a spider is cool. Then you can maybe add a solar system or something. This one needs a moon. And this one here needs green rings. Green rings make the planet look more professional.

They're looking good, orbiting that spider. But something is missing. It needs something red in there. Like, a red square. Yeah. A red square with a blue triangle on top. That looks kinda like a house. Houses suck. Screw that. Uhh. Let's see. Yeah, that works. It looks like a highway down there.

I need a train on this thing. Trains are cool. Especially ones with big puffs of steam coming out the front. I have no idea how to draw trains. I think they look something like this. Yeah, that works. Now it needs a conductor. I hope he doesn't get electrocuted. Maybe he's a semiconductor.

Speaking of semiconductors, the spider needs to be powered somehow otherwise he'll go out. Let's hook him up. Cool. He's fully charged and ready to go now.

Just gotta sign it and it's done!

[YEAH SPIDERS http://welbog.homeip.net/~inferno/images/so/stupid2.png](http://welbog.homeip.net/~inferno/images/so/stupid2.png)

Comment: That's a pretty good signature for paint.  I suspect a tablet is at work here.

Comment: Nope. My tablet is safely at home on my desk. I didn't bring it in to work today.

Comment: That spider isn't working. Somebody close the circuit!

Comment: Don't be pretending to be an EE on here.  Don't even try it.

Comment: I took electronics in high school. What more could there be to know!?

Comment: But a big +1,000 for trying to mimic the famous $233.95 spider.

Comment: My spider is much more shocking.

Comment: -1, no lasers and I'm arachnophobic. :) Throw some lasers in there and I'll flip my vote.

Comment: Screw you, Union boy. I don't need your stinking votes because I have a positive charge. I mean attitude.

Comment: My votes don't stink, buddy!

Comment: Well something sure does and I know for a fact that it's not my art!

Comment: Did you shower today? Did you use soap this time?

Comment: Who the huckleberry do you think I am? I'll have you know that I bathe  on at least a daily basis and that I haven't missed a day in years.

Oh wait I figure it out! The smell is the donuts down the hall. BRB

Comment: Stinky donuts can't be good for you ...

Comment: I reject your spider due to an obvious limb ommission.

Answer (score 16):

You have ignored tags.  That's where they were.  All questions get loaded, then the ignored tags get hidden.  But the space doesn't go away.

Comment: **THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER**, but welbogs is so much cooler. ;-)

Comment: I am so damned cool.

Comment: Even on a (meta)programming site, the cool theatre kids in their leather jackets and aviator sungalsses are stealing my cloudsong.

Comment: the space does go away, on every browser except Chrome / Safari

Comment: @Jeff - I'm a webkit, he's a webkit, they're all webkits, wouldn't you like to be a webkit too?

Answer (score 4):

This happens on Safari and Chrome when you have set certain tags to be hidden instead of dimmed.

Does not happen on Opera, IE, Firefox.

edit: this is *finally* fixed in Safari 5 and Chrome 5.

Comment: It doesn't really bother me, but I think this might be a little bit of abuse of the [status-by-design] tag.  Unless, of course, you want the blank space down there for certain browsers.  Maybe Webkit users are more artistic, and want the space to draw?  I think maybe a [status-super-low-priority], or a [status-if-it-bothers-you-so-much-why-dont-you-fix-it-yourself] tag would be more appropriate?

Comment: OK, fair enough... but this doesn't make it "status-by-design", but rather "status-too-hard-to-fix" (or at least, not worth the effort).