# My gravatar icon is the wrong image

Tags: support, gravatar

Here's what I did...

I have a bunch of images in my gravatar account, but stackoverflow always seemed to display the same one no matter which was picked on gravatar.com. One day my icon spontaneously changed to a different image, though not the one which I had selected.

I decided I'd better fix it, so I clicked 'Change picture' on my SO profile and selected the image I wanted, noting SO's warning about it taking time to change.

A weekend passed, and this morning my SO icon is back to the original (wrong) icon.

Extra info: I've had support queries before regarding my accounts needing to be manually tied together on the different sites because it had become rather muddled. I wonder if this has somehow got something to do with my strange gravatar behaviour.

Comment: `crtl + f5`  Clear out the dusty old cache.

Answer (score 4):

Currently I'm seeing a cartoon chap in a chair. However, if you want a quicker gravatar update one trick is to change your e-mail address. Since you are on gmail this is trivial. Let's pretend your e-mail address is currently `some.user@gmail.com`. You could associate a new gravatar image against `some.user+stackoverflow@gmail.com` and everything will work, and as it is a new e-mail address it'll update immediately. You should see a link marked "[add a new email](http://en.gravatar.com/emails/new)" (on gravatar).

Comment: That's interesting. You're seeing the right icon, and I'm seeing the wrong one. The gravatar checking page also shows me the right one. Let's try clearing my browser cache...

Comment: Yep. Browser cache seemed to fix it.

That's rather annoying.

Answer (score 4):

That's true, [your gravatar should be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns):

[image]