# Allow adding an URL to the image in the user's profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, users, profile-page, images

I'd like to hotlink a different image in my profile, instead of having to upload it to gravatar.

Could we have an option between gravatar (that would remain as default) and a link to an image?

---

If you must know, I'd like to add my [unicorn avatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns) directly, he's really handsome:

[image]
<sub>(source: [appspot.com](https://unicornify.appspot.com/avatar/4dfc8f56817006ef21327d5ff19ce04f?s=128))</sub>

Comment: this is a dupe with either status-planned or status-deferred... I'll be searching (**edit: no dupe**)

Comment: There's one to allow upload of images for using in questions and answers, but I couldn't find this

Comment: Aah, I get it (I missed the "hotlink" part). Makes more sense anyway, considering our previous conversation on that other thread... Yeah, it's late...

Comment: You're aware though that you'd give me full control over your avatar, right? *goes to think of hilarious exploits...*

Comment: I trust you completely @bal, how can someone that created something so beautiful be evil?

Comment: *Muuuuhahahahaha!*

Comment: Just use the link to your unitar image and upload it to gravatar.com, then associate it with a different email address.  Use that email address on meta.

Comment: ran out of votes.. :/

Comment: I am aware of that workaround @tvan (I explicitly say so in my post). But I want to link it directly in case a new version makes my unicorn prettier, to avoid the 24 hour delay, and because I don't want to do it manually

Comment: @Downvoter this would cause pretty grave privacy and/or load issues. Privacy/security because every SO user seeing a post of yours would be accessing your (or anybody else's who uses their own URL) server directly; Load for the same reason. I think that's the reason why services like Gravatar exist (besides the obvious advantage of having the image in one place.)

Comment: They access it right now when they see a question or answer that contains an image @pek

Comment: @Downvoter true, good point.

Comment: @Downvoter - your unicorn will never be pretty, not with those googly eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the "plus in email" trick:

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/mail/addressing/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Sub-addressing

so

`yourname@example.com`

becomes

`yourname+sitename@example.com`

The email still goes to the same place, and you can set up a custom gravatar for it.

edit: the "website" field on your profile serves this function; I don't see us adding another URL field just for the gravatar.

Comment: Well, I knew how to do that, but I wanted to directly link to an image as I do on posts.