# Un-Official April Fools Day 2010 Happenings

Tags: discussion, gravatar, unicorns, april-fools

April fools day is here!  Feel free to post any oddities on the SO family here rather than creating 200000 posts about avatars changing to <s>`Ponies`</s> `Unicorns` with rainbows in the background.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns

Comment: I believe they are actually called unicorns

Comment: @Narsil, yes but a Unicorn is a derivative of a Pony. So therefore you can refer to the unicorns as ponies in the same way you can refer to cats as animals.

Comment: This may just be the day I reach the rep-cap on meta. lol

Comment: Ah, they finally put up the "it's april fool's day" banner after like 10 unicorn questions. lol. a bit late there..

Comment: But still no banner on SO, where most of the questions have started. @ear

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100330180346AAZEE9t

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The irony is that this will probably generate more questions on Meta than the rep recalc.

Comment: Unless someone hasn't logged in for awhile... "hey I logged on to SO only to find that my rep was cut in half AND my gravatar is a pony... I think my account got switched somehow but, oddly, those questions in my profile look like mine! The pony, on the other hand, definitely isn't mine..."

Comment: There was a rep recalc ?? Ahh, so not a bug then.... Happy Easter all!

Answer (score 5):

I hope Google's crawler doesn't associate my unicorn/rainbow avatar with my name in Google Images. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> They are just crazy mixed up animals.  --Gag Halfrunt

Comment: well he's juz zis unicorn ... ya know !

Answer (score 2):

Call me a grumpy old man, but please, **MAKE IT STOP!**

It wasn't funny 4 years ago when [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) did a very similar thing, and it's not funny now.

Oh, and .get off my lawn!  :)

Comment: You are a grumpy old man.

Comment: I couldn't agree with CraigTP more

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's [already activated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44772/unicorns-on-me-avatar) !

Answer (score 1):

I just thought someone had coded an ingenious method of spamming the site and perhaps farming for answers for other sites (like Quora) when I spotted five questions in a row from users with vaguely suspicious names, one rep and various unicorn icons.

Took a few seconds for the April Fools penny to drop.

I hadn't realised how most internet user names looks suspicious when ones head is at a certain angle.

Also - I want to keep my unicorn!

Comment: @David, right click and save image as...

Answer (score 1):

The only user who think all his Christmases (and Easters) have come at one will be [OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies)!

Comment: Horny pony <> unicorn :p

Answer (score 1):

I don't really care about the ponies, but I'm having problems posting comments and answers to Stack Overflow with Firefox 3.6.2.  It briefly shows an image of a lolcat and something about a serious error before blanking out and failing to load something; I try refreshing but it doesn't load, and my text gets lost.  Sometimes it goes through but most of the time it doesn't; it works perfectly fine every time in Internet Explorer 8.  I am using NoScript and Adblock Plus, but I've never had this problem until today.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/something-bad-keeps-happening-to-me

Answer (score -1):

It's been here for 9 hours and 46 minutes already... slow much?

Anyway. I see ponies! Everywhere! (actually apparently they're unicorns)