# Are any two unicorns the same?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, unicorns

Are all unicorns here unique, or are there repeats?  If they are all unique, is it some sort of REALLY cool unicorn-orithm?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has to do with the 2010 April Fool's joke; Unicornify. Since the joke was undeployed several years ago, questions about it are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They should be unique. The MD5 hash of the user's email address or IP is used as the seed for the random number generator, and there are quite a few calls to `random` in the algorithm (in the order of 100-150, I'd estimate).

[image]
<sub>(source: [dilbert.com](http://www.dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It's generated using Magic, seeded by the md5 hash of your e-mail - so any two addresses that cause a hash collision will have identical unicorns. Such unicorn sharing is unfortunate, but necessary, given the current global economy.

Comment: Stupid economy... as a north american (canadian) I am entitled... NO, have the RIGHT to my own unicorn... I don't care what those wall street jerks think!

Answer (score 0):

They're generated, so probably unique.  Have a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)

Answer (score 0):

In the last Federal Unicorn Congress it was generally agreed on by all participants that all unicorns shall be created using the following unicorithm:

```
function unicorithm() {
   let uniqueCorn = "TheLastUnicorn";
   let unique = getNumberOfTimesTimLostHisKeysToday();
   let times = math.random() * unique;
   for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      uniqueCorn = CryptoJS.MD5(uniqueCorn);
   }
   cornHash = uniqueCorn.unicorncat(new Date(milliseconds))
   return cornHash;
}

let uniqueUniCorn = unicorithm();
```

Comment: @TimPost Sorry for dragging your keys into the explicit science of generating unicorns - but the unicorithm was in desperate need of something unique.. ;)