# Allow awarding a bounty to "question" poster at stackapps

Tags: feature-request, bounties, stackapps

Since many "questions" at stackapps are actually finished scripts (e.g. [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2050/threaded-comments)) I'd like to be able to award a bounty to the script itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're linking to my script: I appreciate it, but honestly, it feels a lot more rewarding when I see that a script is actually in use – e.g. be cause the "installed X times" number on userscripts.org goes up, or I notice in screenshots that my script is running there, or people give feedback and suggestions, or leave nice comments, etc.

*Especially* in a place like StackApps, where people list the stuff they have created, the best way to pat people on the back is: actually using the stuff. Because, you know, it's awesome to see people use the stuff you created.

<sub>Another example: My [Unicornify question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) has a score of 199, but what's really awesome is that Unicornify serves 3 requests per second because people actually implemented it on their sites.</sub>