# What is the strange relationship between Stack Overflow and unicorns?

Tags: discussion, unicorns

First, there was a cute animation that played on the first of April. Now a rainbow unicorn can be clearly seen on the Stack Overflow Dev Days 2011 advert. There seems to be a trend here. Is the site actually run by a secret cult that worships unicorns?

**Artist's impression of a unicorn:**

[image: pencil sketch of a unicorn]

Comment: [Unicorns are the magical weaponized form of ponies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479).

Comment: It is just one of the [many magical memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479).

For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns

Comment: Every time the subject of unicorns comes up on Stack Overflow, I can't help but think of [Sparklelord](http://drmcninja.com/comics/2009-11-04-15p65.jpg)...

Comment: What? Did you miss [the second April 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37328/2509)?

Comment: It's what Jeff wants to be when he grows up, and what Jon Skeet turns in to when he clocks (max's out) his badge score.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is the site actually run by a secret cult that worships unicorns?

Yes. Yes it is.

Well, not necessarily *secret* anymore, since I've answered this question.

Comment: You talked too much...

Comment: (rumor: they eat unicorn meat for breakfast)

Comment: no rumour: http://www.thinkgeek.com/caffeine/wacky-edibles/e5a7/

Answer (score 8):

I prefer narwhals.

[image]