# Why is meta in a question and answer format?

Tags: discussion

If meta is to discuss the community outside of the community, then why Q and A?

Wouldn't http://www.discourse.org/ be better?

Comment: Meta was launched nearly 4 years ago, while Discourse was launched... what, 4 months ago?

Comment: Discussion is made up of questions and answers... Given the ear-to-mouth ratio most of us have, answers are usually more valuable than questions.

Comment: "Given the ear-to-mouth ratio most of us have, answers are usually more valuable than questions." -- This gets to a larger point I want to make. You all (or we if you will) have a serious community problem that I think is a philosophical one.

Comment: I think the Q/A format is actually quite good for meta discussions. Of course, attaching the whole reputation system to it is a little weird, since with the way meta voting works reputation a lot more meaningless. But hey, it doesn't really hurt so I don't see a problem with just using the same engine (i.e. as it currently is).

Comment: Who says Meta is (just) for discussing the community outside of the community? What about bug reports, support and feature requests? Discussion is just one aspect of Meta.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @yannis I didn't say "just" but the Q and A uber all doesn't exactly fit every scenario.

Comment: @BilltheLizard so if not discourse, then why not another forum or format.  I think it even says on the SO faq that open ended questions that lend themselves to "discussion" are nor allowed.

Comment: @Jim You didn't say "just", but you did ignore all other aspects of Meta in your question. Do you think discourse or some other format would work for _all_ aspects of Meta?

Comment: Are all the down votes on this question proof enough that it doesn't work for discussion?  I had an idea I wanted to discuss, and people don't like the idea so they down vote, but is the question actually bad?  I don't see why it is, but maybe I'm  missing something.

Comment: @Jim You're missing that meta, while in the same format as other stack sites, doesn't operate the same way. Upvotes/downvotes are for agreement/disagreement here for one. The others differences are listed in the [FAQ].

Comment: In the far distant past, the location for meta jiberjabber UserVoice. Switching to our own dogfood was actually a good thing for all that the engine is not particularly well adapted for some of the stuff we want to do.

Comment: sniff, its smells like advertising.

Answer (score 7):

When all you have is a hammer...

Plus, Meta isn't just discussion. It's discussion + bug reports + support requests + waffles + feature requests. At least *some* of that is pretty well-suited for a Q&A site, and what isn't can be kinda shoehorned in without too much trouble.

Discourse looks promising... For discussion. But integrating it would be kind of a hassle, and would do very little to improve the situation for all of the other purposes Meta exists to serve.

Comment: "discussion + bug reports + support requests + waffles + feature requests" + [unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: "discussion + bug reports + support requests" -- it doesn't work well for any of these, now does it? A regular bug tracker plus a ticket system plus a discussion platform would work a lot better. A pain to integrate, but well.

Comment: Of course, @Raphael. In a world with infinite time and resources, we'd have a fully-integrated dedicated blogging system, a fully-integrated dedicated bug-tracking system, discussion forum, documentation wiki / knowledge base, etc. In this world, we have a few internal systems that are barely adequate for a small team but neither well-integrated nor scalable, we have chat, and... we have meta.

Comment: Why fully integrate? SE provides OAuth so platforms like Discourse are "integrated" as much as we'd need. If we could only move *discussion* out of Meta, I think it would already help. (I'm sure SE Chat is someone's baby, but what about any of the Slack clones?)

Comment: Chat is probably the one successful example of a piece of meta's original domain (idle chat and fraternization) that was broken off into its own system, @Raphael. The second attempt - blogging - has largely ended in failure: even though it did possess the limited integration you describe, it suffered mightily from a lack of effective integration on the main site (both chat and meta have this to some degree) and in particular a lack of integration with the privilege system (you effectively had to "know somebody" to use the system even if you were able to log in).