# Why there are so many unicorns among top-level SO users?

Tags: discussion, gravatar, unicorns, fun

These top users have the same cartoon rainbow unicorns in their avatar:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/227665/codaddict
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/47738/rahul
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/0xa3

What is this cartoon? Where is the connection with SO? Should I watch the cartoon to improve my skills?

Comment: It is a long-running meme, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/140890.

Comment: [My God—it's full of unicorns!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: [It was an April's Fool changing all avatar pictures to unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: Because we love unicorns.

Comment: But he has his own pic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479). This one happens to be one of the most popular, and as such we have quite a few unicorn lovers.

In fact, there are [45 people with 'unicorn' in their bios](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/113812), and only 6 of them are over 10k rep.

Thus, it is my professional opinion that everyone changes their bio to say 'unicorn', as a sign of respect for our dear clippycorn.