# Why some superusers have Unicorn as profile pic?

Tags: support, user-accounts, users, profile-picture, unicorns

Why some superusers(users with awesome reputation points) have Unicorn as profile pic?

I don't understand philosophy behind it.

You can check yourself ->

[This account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227665/codaddict)

[And this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman)

[And this too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat)

[Also this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday)

[Check this too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat)

[This too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers)

[Felling boring ? check this too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47738/rahul)

[Another 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman)

[Here is next](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday)

[I think this list is enough,I am tired! :(](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr)

Don't know how many more users are here with Unicorn.

Comment: Why you have angry birds as profile pic?

Comment: @ShadowWizard , thanks! I changed it , why? You can find it out in my profile info section.

Comment: lol, priceless.

Comment: 3rd and 6th profile pictures are now not unicorns.

Comment: @zixuan , this post is almost 4 years old :) Thanks for the memories!

Answer (score 6):

A few years ago, as an April fools joke, all avatars on the different sites were temporarily changed to unicorns - powered by [unicornify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns).

The situation was/is not specific to Super User:

[Why there are so many unicorns among top-level SO users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179903/why-there-are-so-many-unicorns-among-top-level-so-users?lq=1)

Why unicorns?

It is one of the [many memes of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/140505)...

Comment: And some users just love unicorns regardless of memes: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1005187/sparchaeologist), and many more. :)