# Cannot flag comments made Community♦ regarding dead URLs

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags, community-user

I was digging through some lovely unicorn paraphernalia, when I came across [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns#comment366530_37565) which is now incorrect. I attempted flagging it as 'obsolete', but I got this error message:

[image]

Doesn't Community know that links can sometimes fix themselves after a while? If not, I think we need to teach him, don't you?

EDIT:

It turns out that it's not necessarily a problem with flagging a comment by the Community user, but it is instead a problem with the link validator.

This link, for example, will work if I paste it into my browser's URL, but not if I use it as an inline image:

```
http://unicorn.ü-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png
```

Testing inline below:
[inline test http://unicorn.%C3%BC-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png](http://unicorn.%C3%BC-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png)

However, this link (it doesn't work in the browser), while it works for embedding images (as you can see in the post I linked) gets flagged as 'invalid' by community:

```
http://unicorn.&#252;-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png
```

(cannot post inlining attempt, but see this revision: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/37565/2)

And this link, which works in the browser, also doesn't work for inlining images:

```
http://unicorn.%C3%BC-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png
```

[inline test http://unicorn.%C3%BC-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png](http://unicorn.%C3%BC-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png)

Overall, pretty bugged up stuff here, don't you think?

Comment: Uh, didn't follow you.

Comment: @djechlin you cannot flag a comment made by community for that purpose, if the link has been corrected. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: +1 sounds like bug, if 1) it didn't clean up its comment and 2) you aren't allowed to either.

Comment: Now it's really fixed, most likely the comment will be deleted soon.

Comment: To rule out blacklisting, this URL appears to work (in comments, at least): http://unicorn.ü-wie-geek.de

Comment: The link review queue was a better idea...

Comment: Is the bug here the URL or the comment? I'm confused.

Comment: @Shog9 maybe both. The comment still hasn't been removed since ShaWizDowArd made his edit, and the URL isn't properly parsed I think.

Comment: I'd give the comment at least a day to go away before calling that broken (it might well *be* broken, but it'd hardly be surprising if it didn't re-check the links in real-time). The URL you should probably report separately.

Answer (score 6):

Any user who is able to flag can now flag comments authored by the Community user as *no longer needed*, per changes [made here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369111/51).

Comment: I hope the error message for other comment flag types on Community comments has been modified to more clearly point to the issue. What does it say now?

Answer (score 4):

No, Community♦ is kind of right, there is an invalid link in that post:

[image]

The message is just not quite easy to see, since it pops up at the top of the page, and not near the post, when you pretend to try to edit it.

Comment: But the link does infact work. That's the problem here.

Comment: It is not allowed. (aka blacklisted)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII "invalid" doesn't necessarily mean the link doesn't work. "Link not allowed" implies "invalid link".

Comment: Yes, but just because the host has a UTF character shouldn't mean it's an invalid link, does it?

Comment: I don't know if the link is forbidden or unicode urls are not allowed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm not arguing whether the link _should_ be allowed. By whatever criteria were decided, the link is not allowed (hence considered invalid). Therefore, you not being able to flag it as obsolete is the correct behaviour.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' I disagree. If the Community user messed up for some reason, we should be able to correct him. It's that simple, really. Even if the host itself was blocked, if the URL was harmless (such as a link to a clean PNG, which this is), it should be able to stay IMO.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's an entirely different thing. One would need to have some dev allow that link (I suppose Community doesn't decide which links are allowed and which not by itself). As long as that link is disallowed, Community really should behave as it did.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' very strange. I did some testing in the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/178403/revisions), and it appears that using the unicode character itself doesn't work (and doesn't get flagged), but the UTF-8 escaping of it (which, ironically, allows it to be linked properly) causes community to go off.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Tried URL-encoding it? Maybe that would work.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' that seems to be what causes the community user flagging it and giving me a fit. Still testing though.