# Acknowledging Pictures Posted on this site and then used on this site

Tags: support, creative-commons, reference

If I use pictures taken from this site to post on this site. [Like here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064041/drawing-diagonal-lines-across-a-picture) Do I have to acknowledge where [the pics came from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) each time, or is it ok to recycle material like this from within the site. (I am not referring to taking credit for someone else's work, as I am not professing to be the creator of the pics)

Comment: Do these images come from posts? Users' avatars? Something else?

Comment: there is a link in the link I provided, they are from posts on meta here

Comment: p.s.: I dunno why, but I chuckle every time I see the screenie of the voting for yourself error on your profile.

Comment: Yeh, It makes me smile to.. hey the post I stole the unicorns from was on here.. I added a link...

Comment: If the links I posted on the question here are not clearly marked, pls feel free to edit cheers (it's 4.46am and I'm passed my useby date ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are referring to images you found on Stack Exchange which you want to repost in another post also on Stack Exchange?

If so, I believe that is fine - especially if you are talking about images which were posted in a question/answer; they would fall under the CC-Wiki. I am not immediately sure about taking someone's profile image, though.

You should, therefore, also link to the source, perhaps in a <sub>sub link</sub>, each time you post them.

Comment: yeh, I stole the unicorns, as we are studying image transformations at uni, and they make cute pictures to work with.. any other pics I have created or own.. just wanted to check, as I would forget to acknowledge them and then add the acknowledgemnt as an afterthought

Comment: A person's profile picture may be copywritten. Take mine for example. I made it myself for my little startup Hexware US Copyright law states that anything is implicitly copywritten. The only reason to file for a copyright is to (essentially) prove you made it first. Like exFAT. If someone wrote a closed source version, then someone leaked the code as open source, a filed copyright proves the closed source is the original

Comment: If you wrote an open source one and someone kang'd you, the source tree would prove you wrote it first.

Comment: Clarifying a bit of what @ColeJohnson said, while the original creator would still retain the copyright to their profile picture, the act of uploading it makes it fully licensed under the same license as any and all Stack Exchange content. There's even a little link on the Upload Picture spot to the license terms. Means that, unless someone's breaking the law by using a picture they don't themselves own, all profile pics are fair game to re-use with attribution, same as posts' content. And if they don't themselves own the picture, they don't have the right to use it as a profile image anyway.