# Any way to recover my unicorn?

Tags: feature-request, fun, unicorns

As many of you know, a few years ago, April Fools Day was celebrated by generating an [image of a unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns), complete with rainbows, for each user and displaying that unicorn for the users avatar.  The unicorns were procedurally generated (I believe I read that they were based on the users ID as a seed).

I thought it was wonderful, but at the time I was under a lot of strain to finish a project, and did not save my unicorn.  Is there a way that one might recreate their unicorn for posterity?

Comment: Not sure about the specific seed but balpha released it http://unicornify.appspot.com/

Comment: No but Gravatar has a random unicorn generator. That's what I chose for my Gravatar.

Comment: http://unicornify.appspot.com/use-it

Comment: Gah, you beat me to it!  Curse my slow typing speed!

Comment: Heh, there are a bunch of duplicates of this but they're all closed as duplicates of each other in a circle (a few of which are deleted). Since none of them really mention Unicornfiy and don't really have useful information, I'll just delete the odd circle of duplicates and this can stay.

Comment: Huh, I did a little searching and did not see those.  Unfortunately the word unicorn is thrown around enough on here that it creates a swamp of potential answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The links in the post above no longer quite work, but the unicornify app is still working as of 13Jan14.  Just go to:http://unicornify.appspot.com/use-it and enter your ID.

Once generated, you can simply save the image to your computer. Then upload it to either Gravatar or Stack Exchange itself to use it.

Comment: And incidentally, though it says it wants your email address; you can enter pretty much anything.

Comment: I assume it has the same potential issues of Gravatar security-wise (if you use your real email)?

Comment: @Joe Perhaps. Which is why I noted it needn't be an email at all :)