# Allow Stack Exchange Moderators access to April Fools Day for entire April Fools Day Period

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities, april-fools, unicoins

As a moderator (and somewhat *de facto* first line of support when things go awry), it's helpful when we can reproduce issues and see what the users are seeing.

With the latest April Fools Day (Unicoin, I think), we have no visibility into any changes until they happen in our timezone, causing us to be (in this case) 18 hours behind people who are already [bringing up these issues on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicoins).

Feature Request: Moderators should be able to see April's Fools day features for the entire April Fools day period across the world.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing me to death.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better: *I also don't see it yet*

Comment: April First, responsible for billions in productivity loss

Comment: Are we going to get our own [april fool animation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)?

Comment: O! I thought everyone had decided to post the same april fools day post! I thought people were being remarkably unoriginal

Comment: Why should the devs waste time on this for what is essentially a one-day fad? You are not compelled to respond to those unicoin questions. They can be adequately addressed by regular users who are in the time zone or can be closed as [meta-tag:status-norepro] or too-localized on April 2nd.

Comment: Let me get this straight: spending time on April Fools day features isn't frivolous?

Comment: Why not make everyone have it at the same time? It's confusing for everyone... not just moderators.

Answer (score 18):

Actually **there are no unicoins.**  It's all just a prank on the mods and meta regulars.

Instead of actually implementing something, the devs realized that it would be easier to just get a bunch of users to ask meta questions and raise flags about unicoins as if they existed.  You fake up a few screenshots, tell them all how it *would have* worked, and you're off to the races.

Cost of development: $0
Watching mods try to field questions about an imaginary feature: **priceless**

Answer (score 6):

Change the timezone of the system clock on your machine to another timezone in which it's April 1st.

Comment: "Why are you asking me to change? Am I not good enough the way I am?  I thought you liked me for me." -- *My Computer*

Comment: @GeorgeStocker If you're looking for alternatives, you could always just move to Seoul, if you can get there within the next 19.25 hours.  If that's easier anyway.

Comment: Lets go to Seoul \o/

Comment: @JoeW This only needs to be supported by a handful of moderators, not every single user of the site.  It's also pretty unusual to have a machine that doesn't support changing the timezone.  Most machines aren't built to be used in only one timezone.

Comment: @JoeW The ability to change the date/time requires admin rights; the ability to change the timezone does not.  And again, this only needs to be an option for a handful of moderators; not everyone in the world.

Answer (score 3):

You can gain early access to the Stack Exchange, LLC Unicoin currency by spending ₰2.56 [unicoin].