# Oneboxing has suddenly become too eager (aka oneboxing links formatted as code)

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

Here are a few examples of something I just noticed today, *none* of which previously became oneboxes:

```
      http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/240/the-nineteenth-byte asdfasdf
```

This is a link to a chatroom preceded by zero or more spaces and followed by any arbitrary text. The result is that the chatroom link oneboxes—the expected result is that four or more preceding spaces should convert the entire message into a code block, and any trailing text should prevent oneboxing.

```
        http://i.imgur.com/xVyoS.jpg
```

That's an image link preceded by four or more spaces. Again, the expected result is a code block, but the image oneboxes instead.

The same result is seen (leading spaces not interpreted as code block, but trailing characters prevent oneboxing) with

- links to Q&A (ex. `​        http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37328/180276`)
- links to comments
- links to other chat messages
- links to user profiles
- Amazon links
- Wikipedia links

Some onebox-types that are *not* affected:

- links to SE sites (ex. `​        http://codegolf.stackexchange.com`)

The lists above are by no means comprehensive; they're just the first few things that came to mind that I decided to try.