# Allow customizable "magic links" on a per-site basis.

Tags: feature-request, comments, magic-links

When writing comments, you can type certain "magic links" to link to common help pages. For example, if a new post is lacking a minimal, complete and verifiable example, I can just write

```
Please provide an [mvce].
```

And this will be replaced with the appropriate link. This is extremely convenient on Stack Overflow.

However, lots of the smaller sites have their own frequently used help pages. For example, on one of the sites I'm most active on, Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf, we have a meta post called ["The Sandbox"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/) where users can post challenges to get constructive feedback on how to make their challenge better. If I want to point a user to the sandbox, I have to open a new tab, search for the sandbox, copy and paste the url, and enter the hotlink syntax. It would be a lot more convenient if I could just write:

```
You should try posting this challenge to the [sandbox].
```

And the same idea is applicable on all of the smaller sites. Now, there are a lot of links like this that could be useful. Each site probably has a better picture of useful links for that site than anyone else would.

I propose we add a method to customize this for each site. A moderator can add a shortcut to a list of site-specific shortcuts like this:

```
[sandbox] = http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/
[unicorns] = http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns
[addiction] = http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you
```

And then if someone types one of the magic links on *that particular* site, it would hyperlink to the specified page.