# Can moderators get access to Community user and perform moderation activities?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderators, community-user

According to its profile description, the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user can perform some actions like bumping old unanswered questions, deleting unwanted questions, tag tuning etc., but there are some unmentioned actions which are done by it. It also approves comment flags if it contains abusive language. It also deletes comments if there are three flags on a comment with no positive score. It does [much more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/357396).

In the new days of Stack Overflow, Moderator Elections announcements on Meta were posted by the Community user. Well, it is known that some employee has written it. I have also seen a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns/37565#comment366530_37565) posted by it.

Is this posting behalf of Community possible only for employees? Can diamond moderators use Community and perform moderation activities like deleting comments?

Comment: Assuming the credentials of the community user are only known to SE staff and/or the *impersonate as specific user* is only available to SE developers it is safe to assume  moderators can't perform actions by means of the Community user. Do you have any evidence it isn't?

Comment: @rene There are no credentials for the Community user - there's not even an account. They're just on-site profiles not connected to anything. Also the impersonate feature only exists on the dev environment.

Comment: For performing moderation activities, community moderators are already given a diamond. Why do they need to use a diamond of community user?

Comment: @Pandya The same reason why emplyees wrote comments and meta posts instead of doing themselves. They could have done it under their name but didn't. Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can diamond moderators use Community and perform moderation activities like deleting comments?

**No, we can't;** there's no 'back door' or such. If we delete or flag comments, it's always attributed to our own user.

We can only influence Community's actions indirectly; if we cast a binding spam flag, the Community user will delete and lock the post for us (but that's the same as with 6 spam flags from regular users).

Comment: No, that is not what I ask. It is getting access to Community and deleting comments from its behalf and not deleting from your own account. I mean moderation by the "means of Community and not your own" Is it possible?

Comment: No, we don't have any back doors like that.

Comment: Can you modify answer with that statment?

Comment: It already starts with "No, we can't.", should I make that bold?

Comment: I ask for modification because it looks like you are asking for clarification. It can be like "NO we can't _delete comments or answers through means of Community User_ ".