# Is there an elegant way to view the post images when my country is among the ones blocking Imgur?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

Looks like my country is among the ones blocking Imgur. So, whenever I view the posts with images, I get only a partial view.

Is there an elegant way to view the posts (from Google Chrome or Firefox) other than using the Tor browser?

Comment: Does google translate work for you? You can paste an URL and it translates it, don't know how well that takes on images though. In that way it works sort of like a VPN.

Comment: @Luuklag very creative! However, as we can see [here](https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/73568212/box-clustering-with-matlab?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp) for example, the images keep their original URL so will still be blocked. Edit: however, clicking the image translates it, e.g. [this is the image from my example](https://i-stack-imgur-com.translate.goog/vUfes.png?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp), so there is merit. Answer? :)

Comment: @Luuklag Works like a charm.

Comment: @Masroor do you get to see the images directly, or do you have to click them like Shadow mentioned?

Comment: @Luuklag I need to click on the links.

Comment: This was asked several years ago at Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261455/3648282

Comment: @Rob But this affects all the SE sites and deserves to be asked in the top meta, IMHO.

Comment: Masroor, it's perfectly OK to ask here. There's **11** answers there, most of them very helpful. --- It's common practice to point out duplicates on other Stack Exchange sites, even other well known sites elsewhere, it doesn't affect the open/close status of your question.

Comment: This is another reason to [not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/), folks (though the system could be much better in helping to format the said text properly. That is, making it the path of least resistance).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum There are situations when you must post an image. For example, you are running a LaTeX code and need to show the exact output to the world. What other options are there other than an image?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum on some sites like Travel images seem appropriate although most of the images I see on other sites could have been avoided with benefit to everyone (as you said).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) as a sort of VPN. Just copy the URL of the page you want to see the images of, and paste that directly into Google Translate.

Google then creates a translated link for you, like so:

[image]

Using the link you now redirect traffic through Google, and are able to see the images inside the post body. There are some issues known to occur using this that relate to disturbing the layout of the page, including writing out the vote count, especially when translating pages that contain non-English words.

As pointed out in the comments, you might need to click on the image for it to actually show, as in the first instance it still uses the original Imgur URL. Clicking on the image forces it to open in a (new) tab, and to have a Google URL. For example the image in this post is first passed as:

https://translate.google.com/website?sl=auto&tl=en&hl=nl&client=webapp&u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzQ5H.png

Clicking on it opens it as:

https://i-stack-imgur-com.translate.goog/kzQ5H.png?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=nl&_x_tr_pto=wapp

which is now on a Google domain.

Comment: This is great advice, but it's also fragile. While a country is unlikely to completely block Google, they could easily block `i-stack-imgur.com.translate.goog` instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Archive.org or a similar site (well, assuming that's not blocked too). It's a little slow loading but it doesn't mess up the page at all and you can see everything on the page at once.

Example: [My God—it's full of unicorns](https://web.archive.org/web/20220901150838/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-god-its-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: Big downside is that it's not archiving all pages and takes time until it archives a page.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yes, but you can archive a page you can't visit since you only need to provide the URL, not visit the URL. With a bit of patience, it works quite well. You can archive pretty much anything, including [this question thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20220901195954/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381696/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-view-the-post-images-when-my-country-is-among-the-one).